# Implementing SignalR client callback function with Typescript

Tags: signalr, typescript

I'm trying to make SignalR and Typescript work together.

I've got the following file:

```
/// <reference path="../../vendor/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

interface SignalR {
    roleHub: IRoleHub;
} 

interface IRoleHub {
    server: IRoleHubServer;
    client: IRoleHubClient;
}

interface IRoleHubServer {
    getUserRoles();
}

interface IRoleHubClient {
    populateUserRoles(names: string[]) : IRoleHubClient;
}
```

The following class implements IRoleHub:

```
module Portal.App {
    export class Controller implements IRoleHub {
        role: Portal.App.Model.IRole;

        server: IRoleHubServer;
        client: IRoleHubClient;

        constructor(role: Portal.App.Model.IRole) {
            this.role = role;
            this.server = $.connection.roleHub.server;
            this.client = $.connection.roleHub.client;
        }

        getUserRoles() {
            this.server.getUserRoles();
        }

        populateUserRoles(roles: string[]) {
            console.log('populated');
        }
    }
}
```

I call getUserRoles in another file and my server side function is being invoked, however I'm struggling to implement the populateUserRoles client side callback.

In Javascript, I would have done:

```
connection.client.populateUserRoles = function (roles) {
    [...]
}
```

however my code above generates the following output, which is incorrect:

```
Controller.prototype.populateUserRoles = function (roles) {
                        console.log('populated');
                    };
```

I will appreciate any help with implementing this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way that should work :

```
   constructor(role: Portal.App.Model.IRole) {
        this.role = role;
        this.server = $.connection.roleHub.server;
        this.client = $.connection.roleHub.client;
        this.client.populateUserRoles = (roles)=> this.roles(roles);
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks, it works. However, I would be interested to know if there are any better ways. 

I'm just thinking that the constructor might become a bit messy after I have to implement a lot of client functions within it.

Comment: You can use _.extend to add the member of the class to the hub...but that results in type unsafety.